# Unable to clone from repository even though I have git access

Tags: git, ssh

I'm just confused as to why I'm not able to clone from a git repository even though I have an SSH key.

I try the command

git clone git@github.corp.epic.com:blahblahblah/healthstats.git healthstats

And I get

Cloning into ‘healthstats’…
Permission denied (publickey).
Fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

This is even though I have an SSH key attached to my username.

What is going on here. Can someone tell me why this is?

Comment: Do `ssh -v git@github.corp.epic.com` for debug output. And contact the admin who setup the GH enterprise install.

Comment: Your public key is probably attached to your remote username but you are attempting to clone using `git` username. Contact your admin to fix it. Do what @ceejayoz suggested and you will be able to tell if your key is allowed.